# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: php, security, restriction

I'm using the following code to restrict traffic to a web site unless it was clicked on from the referral domain. For some reason it doesn't work consistently. Sometimes it restricts the site even though the referral is correct. Have no idea why!

```
<?php
// This is to check if the request is coming from a specific domain

$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$refData = parse_url($ref);


if($refData['host'] !== 'allowed-domain.com') {
  // Output string and stop execution
  die("Access Restricted. Internal Use Only.");
}

echo "";
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the Referer is being sent? Users can disable it with privacy settings.

Comment: Referer is a very poor security mechanism, it can easily be spoofed.

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` browser set, can be set to anything, many firewalls and security software set it to blank.

Comment: It seems as if your real question is "What is the best way to keep people off on my website?" The answer would then be to use either an encryption algorithm or a hash algorithm which you send back and forth as a temporary password. There are a number of really good encryption algorithms here on Stack Overflow as well as hashing algorithms.  Do a search on it. :-)